# WebView - Load and Save File

Tags: android, webview

I have a page html, now i want bring it to android into webview. 
Page can save and load file to computer.

Now, when bring it to android. I want using function.

1. Load File :

   ```
   <input id="loader" type="file" accept=".bin" onchange="run(this.files[0]);">
   ```

In android, how to send a file from storage to function `run();`?

2. Save File :

   ```
   window.open('data:application/octet-stream;base64,' + data, 'save.bin');
   ```

In Android, how to save save.bin to storage?

Someone help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your webView

```
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
```

Write this code to allow storage.

Comment: i want code in android to save file. now, i don;t have idea for this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32305414/android-save-data-from-webview Can you try this